# Chern class of tangent sheaf of quintic threefold in $\mathbb{P}^4$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

$\newcommand{\ch}{\mathrm{ch}}$Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ be a quintic threefold, and the ground field $\mathbb{C}$. I'm following [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#Chern_classes_in_algebraic_geometry) method of computing the (total) Chern class of $\mathcal{T}_X$.

We have the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{T}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^4}|_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(5) \rightarrow 0 $ where $\mathcal{O}_X(5)$ is the normal sheaf $\mathcal{N}_{X/\mathbb{P}
^4}$. By the axiom of Chern classes where for short exact sequences $0 \rightarrow E' \rightarrow E \rightarrow E'' \rightarrow 0$ we have $ \ch(E) = \ch(E') \ch(E'')$, we have 
\begin{align}
\ch(\mathcal{T}_X ) \ch( \mathcal{O}_X(5) ) &= \ch( \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^4}|_X ) \\
&= (1+h)^5 \\
&=1 + 5h+10h^2+10h^3+5h^4+h^5 \\
&= 1 + 5h+10h^2+10h^3.
\end{align}
where $h$ is the hyperplane class in the Chow ring $A^\bullet(X)$, and we have $\ch( \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^4}|_X ) = (1+h)^5$ by applying the same axiom, this time to the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^4}} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^4}}(1)^{\oplus 5} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^4} \rightarrow 0 $, and using that $\ch(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^4}(1)) = 1+h$.

I have a question at this point: why are $5h^4$ and $h^5$ zero in the third to fourth line of the computation? I know that $h$ is a hyperplane class in $H^2(\mathbb{P}^4, \mathbb{Z})$, and it generates the ring which is in fact of the form
$$  H^2(\mathbb{P}^4, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[h]/h^5. $$
So I can see why the $h^5$ goes to zero, but what about $5h^4$?

For completeness, the computation ends with
$$ \ch(\mathcal{T}_X) =\frac{1+5h+10h^2+10h^3}{1+5h} = \cdots = 1+10h^2-40h^3. $$

Many thanks for any answers.

Comment: The quintic threefold is a threefold, so its cohomology only goes up to degree six and vanishes in degree eight.

Comment: Of course, thanks very much!

Comment: Be carefull, you wrote $ch(-)$ instead of $c(-)$. For example $c(\mathcal{O}_X(1))=1+h$ while $ch(\mathcal{O}_X(1))=\exp(h)$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot that $\mathrm{ch}$ is for the Chern characteristic whereas $c$ is for Chern class. Thanks!